# Can someone kindly explain this code snippet?

Tags: java

can someone please explain, preferably in detail exactly what is going on in the following lines of code ?

```
originalString = input.nextline;
int length = originalString.length;
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0 ; i --) 
    String reverse = reverse + originalString.charAt(i);
```

Comment: You are reversing the order of the characters on such ```originalString``` but you have to declare String reverse before the loop

Comment: Does this code currently compile? `reverse needs to be defined before the loop`

Comment: This code has many compiler errors. It is difficult to understand what it does until you fix these errors.

Comment: A generic hint that might be useful: get an IDE like Eclipse (it's free), correct all source code errors until it compiles, and then execute it in the debug mode, stepping throught it line-by-line, and looking at the values of the variables.Once you get used to it, it's much easier than asking on Stackoverflow ;-).

Answer (score 1):

`originalString= input.nextline;` asks for input and saves it in the variable `originalString`.

`int length= originalString.length;` Gets the length of this variable (the input) and saves it as `length`

`for (int i= length -1; i >=0; i --)` is essentially a loop that runs as many times as the variable has characters.

`String reverse= reverse + originalString.charAt(i);` This is going to throw an error because you're calling reverse as it's not yet defined.

Also the loop should be like this:

```
for (int i = length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    String reverse = reverse + originalString.charAt(i);
}
```

The loop needs to be opened and closed using the curly braces. You might also want to read a bit about java indentation best practices here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html

Comment: "Also the loop should be like this:" look at your code carefully (or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are many syntax errors with the code. Try fixing them and show what you have tried. Basically the code snippet is doing `reverse()`, working code with explanation:

```
// 1. Read a string 
String originalString = "stackoverflow"; // or input.nextLine();
// 2. Get the length of the string
int originalStringLength = originalString.length();
// 3. declare a string that can hold reverse of original
String reverseString = "";

// 4. Loop through and add characters in reverse order using index
for(int i= originalStringLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverseString = reverseString + originalString.charAt(i);
}

// 5. Print to check
System.out.println(reverseString);
```

Executing the above here: http://www.javarepl.com/term.html should give you:

```
wolfrevokcats
```

Comment: You need to initialize String reverseString = "";

Comment: In for loop: for(int i = originalStringLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) . You need to include index 0. The output should be wolfrevokcats

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This code mainly used for reversing the string. But you are declaring the reverse variable inside the loop. For every iteration of loop a new reverse will be declared and older data available in that reverse variable will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Complete Working Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the word");
            String originalString = input.nextLine(); //Asks & Stores the input from user in String variable called originalString.
            int length = originalString.length(); //Calculates the length of the input String.
            String reverse = ""; //Declares the String variable called reverse.
            for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //loops from (length -1) to 0 (Both indices inclusive)
                reverse = reverse + originalString.charAt(i); //stores the last character followed by second to last and so on.
            }
            System.out.println("Reverse of " + originalString + " is " + reverse);
        }
    }
```

Output:

Please enter the word

FooBar

Reverse of FooBar is raBooF

Process finished with exit code 0